# how do you view the results of a database in a new activity?

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, view

I am currently creating a database to store a list of names and coordinates of service stations. However I cannot view the database when i click the view button. Here is my code: `

```
public String getData() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_COORDINATES};
        Cursor c = myDatabase.query(DATABASE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        String result = "";

        int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
        int iCoordinates = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_COORDINATES);

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext())
        {
            result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iName) + " " + c.getString(iCoordinates) + "\n";



        }

        return result;
    }`
```

Does anybody see a problem with this code?

Comment: We really need to see the problem you are facing, like the exception you get, and on which line.

Comment: do you print the Data somewhere? A textview? somewhere?

Comment: In the new activity i set the textview to the result of my database, in the following code.

'TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSqlInfo);
 
        Stations info = new Stations(this) ;
        info.open();
        String data = info.getData();
        info.close();
        tv.setText(data);'

Comment: sorry i dont know how to format code?

Comment: my application forces close and the errors are in the LogCat

Comment: So, can you share the logcat?

Answer (score 0):

Your cursor might not contain any rows.  If so, c.getString() will throw exception.

moveToFirst() returns false on error.  Do your loop like this:

```
if (c.moveToFirst())
{
 do
 {
   result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iName) + " " + c.getString + "\n"; 
 } while (c.moveToNext())
}
```

then you can deal with why your table has no rows if this is in fact the case...

Comment: That's a really long-winded way of iterating over the cursor. Just do `while (c.moveToNext()) { ... }` instead.

Comment: My problem was that I had DATABASE_NAME instead of DATABASE_TABLE